# javascript print output in reverse order

Tags: javascript

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">  
            for (i=0;i < 10; i++) {
      document.write(i);
     }  
</script>
```

How can I print the output of this code which is 0123456789 backwards?

Comment: read the documentation before asking.. `for (i=10;i > 0; i--)`

Comment: `document.write(9-i);`

Answer (score 1):

just set index as highest value, then run it to -1, javascript will automaticly break it at 0.

```js
for (var i=9; i > -1; i-=1) {
      box.innerHTML += i+" <br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

*Edit:* 
Reasons to use a html element and write to that instead of using document.write can be found here:
[Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: What does div's and boxes have to do with this question? Don't think that was part of the question.

Comment: @CharlieFish I really don't care tbh, i will not support the use of document.write..

Comment: That would be a great thing to include in your answer. Why you didn't use `document.write` and why your solution is better would be great things to put in answers. :)

Comment: Valid point i suppose, adding a link to another post explaining it in details :)

Comment: Also remember the question asks it to print from 9 to 0. Your code currently prints 10 to 0.

Comment: fine.. my faith in humanity just dropped a bit if it's really come to the point where someone can't change a 10 to a 9 by themselves haha :P